# How can I simulate form authentication in Tomcat using JMeter?

Tags: tomcat, jmeter, j-security-check

I'm very new to JMeter, but I have some ideas of what JMeter could be used for. Also I have a Tomcat application with form authentication enabled. The thread I'm trying to use consists of:

- HTTP Request Defaults
- HTTP Cookie Manager
- HTTP Header Manager

and the following set of HTTP samplers:

- logout page (`/app/logout.jsp`)
- login page (`/app/login.jsp`)
- j_security_check (/`app/j_security_check`)

where Follow Redirects and Use KeepAlive are enabled. I cannot figure out why the j_security_check request response redirects to `logout.jsp`. After checking the HTTP response in Chrome, I've noticed that such request redirects to index.jsp, but never to the log out page if the credentials are fine. First of all, I had an idea that I didn't imitate all browser HTTP headers, but I've failed after I added all of them to HTTP Header Manager:

```
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.859.0 Safari/535.2
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/whapp/index.jsp
```

But even after specifying all of them, I cannot simulate the authentication... Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try recording the login process, or were these all done manually?

If manually, there could be a parameter missing from one of your requests.

If recorded, there could be a hardcoded parameter that needs to be dynamic (JSessionID, etc.)  You may need to add a GET with a regex to retrieve this value and pass to your POST.

If the JSessionID is expected as a parameter, you won't be able to pass it through the cookie manager, you'll need to do it as an HTTP parameter.

For a rundown on recording, please see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: Thank you for reply, BlackGaff. All these were done manually. I scrupulously checked each HTTP header, and any header is quite the same as it comes from Chrome,.. except of the JSESSIONID cookie that's different almost after each redirect (despite I included HTTP Cookie Manager). It's a bit strange... You mentioned about recording. What did you actually mean? Does JMeter provide such kind of features?