# Tomcat: Multiple authentication schemes for a single web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, tomcat, forms-authentication

My web application uses internal web API (simple AJAX requests from a browser as it's the major client) that's eventually supposed to be exposed externally for the 3rd parties. Since the API is and must be protected with the security constraints in `web.xml`, a user or a client must be authenticated. Currently, there's a custom form authenticator implemented, it performs some additional checks and actions, and then simply delegates the further authentication processing to the `FormAuthenticator` class the custom authenticator is derived from. This works really nice yet, because a user is simply forced to login and pass authentication, and the only client is a web browser.

But FORM authentication is not very suitable for another kinds of clients: let's say an Android client, various 3rd-party clients, etc. Too pass the form authentication they all must simulate the behavior I was looking for in this question: [How can I simulate form authentication in Tomcat using JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246759/how-can-i-simulate-form-authentication-in-tomcat-using-jmeter) . After some investigation of the Tomcat source code, I've got an idea that it should be possible to extend the `AuthenticatorBase` class to implement own way of authentication (like `FormAuthenticator` or `BasicAuthenticator.java` do). What I tried to do was:

```java
public final class SimpleAuthenticator extends AuthenticatorBase {

    private static final String USERNAME_PARAMETER = "username";
    private static final String PASSWORD_PARAMETER = "password";

    @Override
    protected boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response, LoginConfig config) throws IOException {
        final Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        final String ssoId = (String) request.getNote(REQ_SSOID_NOTE);
        if ( principal != null ) {
            if ( ssoId != null ) {
                associate(ssoId, request.getSessionInternal(true));
            }
            return true;
        }
        if ( ssoId != null && reauthenticateFromSSO(ssoId, request) ) {
            return true;
        }
        final String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        final String requestURI = request.getDecodedRequestURI();
        final boolean login = requestURI.equals(contextPath + "/authenticate");
        if ( !login ) {
            response.sendError(SC_FORBIDDEN);
            return false;
        }
        final String username = request.getParameter(USERNAME_PARAMETER);
        final String password = request.getParameter(PASSWORD_PARAMETER);
        final Realm realm = context.getRealm();
        final Principal authenticatedUserPrincipal = realm.authenticate(username, password);
        if ( authenticatedUserPrincipal == null ) {
            response.sendError(SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return false;
        }
        register(request, response, authenticatedUserPrincipal, "SIMPLE", username, password);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Simply speaking, I'd like to use something like `/%CONTEXT_PATH%/authenticate?username=%USERNAME%&password=%PASSWORD%` to authenticate a user with my custom non-form `SimpleAuthenticator`. Not really sure if `BasicAuthentication` would be better for such a case, but I got the following issues with the example above:

- Tomcat allows to specify multiple `Valve`'s in `context.xml`. If the another authenticator is added to the `context.xml` file, then every secured resource is processed with every authenticator. (In principle, I understand why it happens, but can they be separated for different resources?)
- `/%CONTEXT_PATH%/authenticate` is not accessible (HTTP 404). (Not clear yet knowing that `/j_security_check` is simulated somehow.)
- I couldn't find a way to specify multiple authentication schemes in Tomcat, so "old" web browser client could still use `FormAuthenticator` (like it does today), but the "light-weight" clients could use that simplified authentication I tried to implement with `SimpleAuthenticator`. (Don't even know if it's possible -- that is the core)
- As far as I understood the servlet specification, only one `login-config` is allowed for entire web-application. (Well, should I have use another web app to provide the API?)
- I saw some mentions to implement custom authentication via `Filter`, but if it's possible -- I'd like to keep the authenticator module separately in a single place (like it already is and confirmed with [Tomcat: Custom form authenicator in a web application, not as a stand-alone JAR module. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447146/tomcat-custom-form-authenicator-in-a-web-application-not-as-a-stand-alone-jar) ). However I'm very ok to review the general concept I use from scratch.

I suspect that I'm doing a quite wrong thing and have total understanding, but I don't believe that there's no way to implement multiple authentication schemes in Tomcat.

Is there any way to provide multiple authentication schemes to extract the authentication out of `FormAuthetication` (for light-weight clients)? Your help would be really very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This limitation drives me crazy too

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line: You cannot configure multiple authentication schemes for the same web application in Tomcat.
You configure one auth-method that will be used for the authentication in the `web.xml`:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Tomcat map on the authenticator for the web application authentication.
For example, for the `CLIENT-CERT` it will use `org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SSLAuthenticator`
The mapping is in the file `org/apache/catalina/startup/Authenticators.properties`

For purpose you describe in the question you may use regular Tomcat Form Authenticator (`<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>`)

The following code will authenticate a user:

```
String url = "j_security_check?j_username=" + username + "&j_password=" + password;
String redirectUrl = response.encodeRedirectURL(url);
response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
```

When you first access application authenticate a user by execution URL above.
Also, you can use Form Authenticator for “old” code :) 
Please note, the code above uses `GET` method. 
I recommend to submit same parameters in `POST` method to `j_security_check` (you can do it in AJAX).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as far as I remember that cannot work like this, because `FormAuthenticator` requires a special login sequence based on redirects (so keeping the state between redirections). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246759/how-can-i-simulate-form-authentication-in-tomcat-using-jmeter

Comment: Did you try to execute URL?  it works in my environment. I do believe I help you with your question.

Comment: A half year later, but I still feel I have to reply. :) I was not quite correct about redirects, though the real issue was and still is: if a client is trying to request a secured resource after authentication and then having session invalidated (after session timeout, for example), the resource request is forwarded to the login page, no matter what the type of the secured resource is (you request JSON, and you get HTML login page -- this is what `FormAuthenticator` brings). I could rely on HTTP status code (could I?), but sending the login page back is excessive and somewhat horrible